# Static networking via shared internet

Tags: debian, ubuntu, networking

So I have a old Pentium 3 PC with Debian LXDE(but I would just prefer to SSH into it's terminal) and an HP probook 4530s laptop with Ubuntu 15.04.

My laptop is connected via wifi to my home router. My old PC however has driver problems with it's wifi and the drivers had some make error which I don't want to look into ATM. However I have a crossover cable connected to it and my laptop. So this is what I want to do:

1)Connect my laptop and PC to a static network hosted by my laptop. 2)Share my laptops internet connection to that new static network.

Note:I used to know how to do static networking with Cisco, but I think I forgot some key things. The version of Debian is 8.20 and I would like to use it as a server.

Comment: There is already similar posts: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/connecting-to-a-network-via-another-pc?rq=1 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/static-dns-setup-on-client-of-shared-internet-connection?rq=1